# How to fade an object evenly into transparency to give it distance look in blender 2.82

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transparency

I'm trying to achieve this depth/distance look effect, where part of the object that is closest to the camera will be solid but farther the object is from the camera I need it to fade evenly into the distance. I'm going for like a UFO look. I can easily do this effect in 2.79 with the mist setting and render it in transparent but it's different in blender 2.82. What is the best option to achieve this effect in blender 2.82?

UPDATE, I figured out the look I'm going for, here is the image and my nodes setup but my new question is, is there any way of not using the Depth pass because the Depth pass is causing sharp and low resolution edge to my object.    [image]

Comment: Could you add a picture of an example of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I added a picture and a update to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a still image you could  make the material fade to transparent from the front to the back of the object using the material itself (I realize this would not work if the objects are animated and distance to camera is controlling transparency). Not sure what your use case is.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it and see how well it looks